# Using GCOV_PREFIX and GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, gcov

So I am compiling all of my code under folder:

```
/root/a
```

With several subdirectories such as:

```
/root/a/b
```

And I am trying to have the gcda files placed in:

```
/root/a-coverage
```

With subdirectories still correctly set up. I know it's possibly using GCOV_PREFIX, but I can't seem to use it and it's partner GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP correctly.

I would also prefer to not have to use hardcoded absolute filepaths, so this:

```
../a-coverage
```

would be better than this:

```
/root/a-coverage
```

Anyone know how to do this correctly? For some reason no matter how I set these things the gcda files still end up /root/a...

Comment: How do you pass those values and what values are you passing?

Comment: How do I pass what values? For gcov?

Comment: If for gcov then:
export GCOV_PREFIX="flarp"
export GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP="42"

I have tried combinations of "/root/a-coverage", "a-coverage" "../a-coverage" and default strip, 1, and 2.

Comment: Okay I had what you wanted with `GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP=N` and `GCOV_PREFIX=../coverage` having N the number of directories in the full path of where your binary is run, "plus 1". So I have `/home/baris/temp/gcov/src/test.c` and stripping 6 directories and having the prefix `../coverage` I have `/home/baris/temp/gcov/coverage/test.gcda` when test is run. Tell me if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately no it did NOT work...it's still placing in in /root/a!!

Comment: Environment variables seem to be totally ignored, are you building and running the binary on the same terminal? And are you sure that `GCOV_PREFIX` and `GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP` are defined on the terminal that you're "running" the binary?

Comment: Yes I am, I have checked to make sure they're defined. It's odd because they were sort of working earlier, and they only just recently broke. And then I couldn't figure out how to put it back together.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83775/discussion-between-roguebantha-and-baris-demiray).